# Connecting multiple UI objects with signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt

I have many line edits on the form created in the Qt creator designer panel. I want to connect them with the signal and the slot:

```
connect(ui->lineEdit_AmperageMaxCode,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
this,SLOT(slot_ConvertCodesInValues(QString)));
```

Is there a way to not use the `connect()` for each object, but do it with a loop or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all `QLineEdit` children from your widget using [`findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren):

```
QList<QLineEdit*> lineEdits = this->findChildren<QLineEdit*>();
```

and then connect their signals using a loop.

If you want to do it only for some `QLineEdit` instances, you can give them a specific name, and use it as a parameter for `findChildren` (see the documentation).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried a similar solution and there was a compilation error. 
    codesVector.push_back(*ui->lineEdit_AmperageMaxCode);
    codesVector.push_back(*ui->lineEdit_AmperageMinCode);
    for(int i=0;i<codesVector.size();i++)
    {
        connect(codesVector[i],SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(slot_ConvertCodesInValues(QString)));
    }
I tried yours, but the same error: 'QLineEdit::QLineEdit(const QLineEdit&)' is private   Q_DISABLE_COPY(QLineEdit). How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't store values and push back dereferenced pointers. By analogy to my answer, you should have `vector<QLineEdit*>` and then `.push_back(ui->lineEdit_AmperageMaxCode);`. Note the star in variable declaration, and no star in push back.  Note also that in my solution you are already using an existing container from `QWidget` and you don't need to build your own collection of items, which you will have to keep up to date with the GUI.